# Evaluating expressions with various mathematical methods

Tags: java, beginner, math-expression-eval

I have started to learn Java and I need your critique for my first program. It is an interpreter that can calculate any expression including `abs()`, `sqrt()`, `min()`, `max()`, `round()` and `pow()`.

What can you say about this? Are there any code defects or pointless comments?

`Main` class

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    static boolean Error=false;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Type an expression to calculate \n" +
                "abs(x) function returns absolute value of x\n" +
                "sqrt(x) function returns square root of value x\n" +
                "min(x,y,…) function returns a minimum value between x,y,...\n" +
                "max(x,y,…) function returns a maximum value between x,y,...\n" +
                "round(x) function returns a round value of x\n" +
                "pow(x,y) function returns an exponentiation of x,y\n" +
                "Type \"exit\" to exit");
        while (true){
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String stringForProcessing =read.readLine(); //Input a string to work with it
            String output= Calculating.calculating(stringForProcessing); //Calculating

            System.out.println(output);//Output
            Error=false;
        }
    }
}
```

`Calculating` class

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Calculating {
    static String calculating(String workingString){
        ArrayList<String> separatedString = new ArrayList<>();
        int Position=0;
        boolean Negative=false;
        if(Main.Error){                                                //return error report
            return(workingString);
        }
        while(Position<workingString.length()){                        //reducing spaces
            if(workingString.charAt(Position)==' '){
                while (((Position)<workingString.length())
                        &&(workingString.charAt(Position)==' ')){
                    Position++;
                }
            }
            else if (workingString.charAt(Position)=='-'&&(Position==0 //checking value for negativity
                    || workingString.charAt(Position-1)=='-'
                    || workingString.charAt(Position-1)=='+'
                    || workingString.charAt(Position-1)=='*'
                    || workingString.charAt(Position-1)=='/')){
                Negative=true;
                Position++;

            }
            else  if ((workingString.charAt(Position)=='-'             //checking for repeating operators
                    || workingString.charAt(Position)=='+'
                    || workingString.charAt(Position)=='*'
                    || workingString.charAt(Position)=='/')
                    &&(Position==0
                    || workingString.charAt(Position-1)=='-'
                    || workingString.charAt(Position-1)=='+'
                    || workingString.charAt(Position-1)=='*'
                    || workingString.charAt(Position-1)=='/')){
                Main.Error=true;return("Error: two or more operators in a row");
            }

            separatedString.add(Character.toString(workingString.charAt(Position)));
            if (workingString.charAt(Position)=='('){                 //Creating bracer stack to parse

                int BrcrStack=1;
                String Temp="";
                while (((Position+1)<workingString.length())){
                    switch (workingString.charAt(Position+1)){
                        case '(':BrcrStack++;break;
                        case ')':BrcrStack--;break;
                    }


                    Position++;
                    if(BrcrStack!=0){
                        Temp+=workingString.charAt(Position);
                    }
                    else {break;}

                }
                if(BrcrStack!=0){
                    Main.Error=true;return("Error: missing \")\"");
                }
                separatedString.set(separatedString.size()-1, calculating(Temp));
            }

            else if (Character.isDigit(workingString.charAt(Position))){    //Bolting numbers
                while (((Position+1)<workingString.length())&&(Character.isDigit(workingString.charAt(Position+1))
                        || workingString.charAt(Position+1)=='.') ){
                    separatedString.set(separatedString.size()-1,
                            separatedString.get(separatedString.size()-1)+workingString.charAt(Position+1));
                    Position++;
                }
                try {
                    Float.valueOf(separatedString.get(separatedString.size()-1));}
                catch(Exception e){
                    Main.Error=true;return("Error: multiple points");
                }

                if(Negative){                                      //Negate parameter
                    separatedString.set(separatedString.size()-1,Float.toString(-(Float.valueOf(separatedString.get(separatedString.size()-1)))));
                    Negative=false;
                }
            }
            else if (Character.isAlphabetic(workingString.charAt(Position))){  //Bolting functions
                while (((Position+1)<workingString.length())
                        &&(Character.isAlphabetic(workingString.charAt(Position+1))) ){
                    separatedString.set(separatedString.size()-1,
                            separatedString.get(separatedString.size()-1)+workingString.charAt(Position+1));
                    Position++;
                }
                switch (separatedString.get(separatedString.size()-1)){        //Checking functions
                    case "abs":break;
                    case "sqrt":break;
                    case "min":break;
                    case "max":break;
                    case "round":break;
                    case "pow":break;
                    case "exit":System.exit(0);
                    default: {
                        Main.Error=true;return("Error: unknown function \""+separatedString.get(separatedString.size()-1)+"\"");
                    }
                }
                if ((Position+1)==workingString.length()||workingString.charAt(Position+1)!='(')   //Parsing function parameters
                {
                    Main.Error=true;return("Error: missing \"(\" after "+"\""+separatedString.get(separatedString.size()-1)+"\" "+ "function");
                }

                ArrayList<String> Temp = new ArrayList<>();
                int BrcrStack=1;
                Temp.add("");
                while (((Position+2)<workingString.length())){
                    switch (workingString.charAt(Position+2)){
                        case '(':BrcrStack++;break;
                        case ')':BrcrStack--;break;
                        case ',': if (BrcrStack==1){Temp.add("");Position++;continue;}break;
                    }


                    Position++;
                    if(BrcrStack!=0){Temp.set(Temp.size()-1,Temp.get(Temp.size()-1)+Character.toString(workingString.charAt(Position+1)));}
                    else {break;}
                }
                if(BrcrStack!=0){
                    Main.Error=true;return("Error: missing \")\"");}
                Position++;

                float FuncArr[]=new float[Temp.size()];
                for (int i=0;i<Temp.size();i++){

                    Temp.set(i, Calculating.calculating(Temp.get(i)));
                    if (Temp.get(i).length()==0){
                        Main.Error=true;return("Error: missing expression");}
                    FuncArr[i]=Float.valueOf(Temp.get(i));
                }

                switch (separatedString.get(separatedString.size()-1)){     //Calculating functions
                    case "abs":if (FuncArr.length==1) {
                        separatedString.set(separatedString.size()-1,Float.toString(Math.abs(FuncArr[0])));}
                    else {
                        Main.Error=true;return("Error: \"abs\" function needs only one argument");}break;
                    case "sqrt":if (FuncArr.length==1) {
                        double a=FuncArr[0];
                        separatedString.set(separatedString.size()-1,Double.toString(Math.sqrt(a)));}
                    else {
                        Main.Error=true;return("Error: \"sqrt\" function needs only one argument");}break;
                    case "min":separatedString.set(separatedString.size()-1,Float.toString(Min(FuncArr))) ;break;
                    case "max":separatedString.set(separatedString.size()-1,Float.toString(Max(FuncArr))) ;break;
                    case "round":if (FuncArr.length==1) {
                        separatedString.set(separatedString.size()-1,Float.toString(Math.round((FuncArr[0]))));}
                    else {
                        Main.Error=true;return("Error: \"round\" function needs only one argument");}break;
                    case "pow":if (FuncArr.length==2) {
                        separatedString.set(separatedString.size()-1,Double.toString(Math.pow(FuncArr[0],FuncArr[1])));}
                    else {
                        Main.Error=true;return("Error: \"pow\" function needs only two arguments");}break;
                }
            }
            Position++;
        }

        ArrayList<String> ResultArr = new ArrayList<>();
        if(Negative){                                      //Negate parameter
            separatedString.set(separatedString.size()-1,Float.toString(-(Float.valueOf(separatedString.get(separatedString.size()-1)))));
        }

        ArrayList<String> Stack = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        while (i<separatedString.size()){               //Converting expression to postfix notation
            if (separatedString.get(i).length()==1&&(separatedString.get(i).charAt(0)=='+'||separatedString.get(i).charAt(0)=='-'||separatedString.get(i).charAt(0)=='/'||separatedString.get(i).charAt(0)=='*')){
                if(Stack.size()==0){
                    Stack.add(separatedString.get(i));
                }else {
                    if ((separatedString.get(i).charAt(0) == '+' || separatedString.get(i).charAt(0) == '-') && (Stack.get(Stack.size() - 1).charAt(0) == '*' || Stack.get(Stack.size() - 1).charAt(0) == '/')) {
                        Stack.add(separatedString.get(i));

                    } else {
                        Stack.add(separatedString.get(i));
                        Stack.add(separatedString.get(i+1));
                        i++;
                        while (Stack.size() > 0) {
                            ResultArr.add(Stack.get(Stack.size()-1));
                            Stack.remove(Stack.size() - 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                ResultArr.add(separatedString.get(i));
            }
            i++;
        }
        while (Stack.size() > 0) {
            ResultArr.add(Stack.get(Stack.size()-1));
            Stack.remove(Stack.size() - 1);
        }
        i=0;
        while (ResultArr.size()>1){       //Calculating postfix expression
            if (ResultArr.get(i).length()==1&&(ResultArr.get(i).charAt(0)=='+'||ResultArr.get(i).charAt(0)=='-'||ResultArr.get(i).charAt(0)=='/'||ResultArr.get(i).charAt(0)=='*')){

                switch (ResultArr.get(i).charAt(0)){
                    case '+':ResultArr.set(i-2,Float.toString(Float.valueOf(ResultArr.get(i-2))+Float.valueOf(ResultArr.get(i-1))));ResultArr.remove(i);ResultArr.remove(i-1);break;
                    case '-':ResultArr.set(i-2,Float.toString(Float.valueOf(ResultArr.get(i-2))-Float.valueOf(ResultArr.get(i-1))));ResultArr.remove(i);ResultArr.remove(i-1);break;
                    case '*':ResultArr.set(i-2,Float.toString(Float.valueOf(ResultArr.get(i-2))*Float.valueOf(ResultArr.get(i-1))));ResultArr.remove(i);ResultArr.remove(i-1);break;
                    case '/':ResultArr.set(i-2,Float.toString(Float.valueOf(ResultArr.get(i-2))/Float.valueOf(ResultArr.get(i-1))));ResultArr.remove(i);ResultArr.remove(i-1);break;
                }
                i=0;
            }
            i++;
        }

        String Result="";
        for (String aResultArr : ResultArr) {
            Result += aResultArr;
        }

        if (Float.valueOf(Result)==Math.floor(Float.valueOf(Result))){
            Result=Integer.toString(Math.round(Float.valueOf(Result)));
        }
        return Result;
    }

    static float Min(float Arr[]){
        float Min=Arr[0];
        for (int i=1;i<Arr.length;i++){
            if (Arr[i]<Min){Min=Arr[i];
            }
        }
        return Min;
    }
    static float Max(float Arr[]){
        float Max=Arr[0];
        for (int i=1;i<Arr.length;i++){
            if (Arr[i]>Max){Max=Arr[i];
            }
        }
        return Max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Formatting

- [Your variable names should start with a lower case letter by convention.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java)
- Try to have spaces around operators (`+`, `==` etc.)
- Try to have spaces after `if`, `while` etc.
- don't have superlong lines. Somebdoy recommends hardlimit on 80 chars, somebody a soft limit on 120 chars, it doesn't matter. Simply try to have shorter lines if it's possible.
- [generally, these formatting conventions are good to follow](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) (As a baseline, not as a hard rule. They are quite aged, don't contain information about some of the newer Java features (annotations, generics...), enforce the nowadays-controversial spaces instead of tabs and a hard limit of 80 chars-per line.)
- instead of `ArrayList<Something> list = new ArrayList<>();`, use `List<Something> list = new ArrayList<>();` See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/polymorphism-why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-n) or [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2003/jw-0801-toolbox.html).
- anyway, you got the formatting pretty much right

### Code

1. This:

   ```
   String result = "";
   for (String aResultArr : resultArr) {
       result += aResultArr;
   }
   ```

   [is horribly wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65727/1273080) Strings in Java are immutable, which means that you can't add anything to an existing String. What happens instead is that a new String is allocated and all the characters are copied. This is a killer when used in a loop.

   The right way is to use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

   ```
   StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   for (String aResultArr : resultArr) {
       resultBuilder.append(aResultArr);
   }
   String result = resultBuilder.toString();
   ```

   By the way, `"some" + "thing"` gets internally compiled to `new StringBuilder().append("some").append("thing").toString()` anyway (because of the String immutability I talked about).
2. You should generally split your code to have fewer loops, less indenting, much more methods. That way, it will be a lot more readable, maintainable (and therefore less error-prone). For example, this code in the main parsing `while` loop:

   ```
   // reducing spaces
   if (workingString.charAt(position) == ' ') {
       while ((position < workingString.length())
               && (workingString.charAt(position) == ' ')) {
           position++;
       }
   }
   ```

   This could be a separate method `skipSpaces()`.

   Or, even better, move it out from the main loop. Do you want to strip the user input of all spaces? Do it right away when you read it!

   ```
   // Input a string to work with it, strip it of all spaces
   String stringForProcessing = read.readLine().replace(" ", "");
   ```

   Or, again, in a method, so it's possible to have a high-level overview over the code:

   ```
   // Input a string to work with it
   String stringForProcessing = read.readLine();
   stringForProcessing = stripOfSpaces(stringForProcessing);
   ```
3. Comment your code. Don't explain what it does. For example,

   ```
   // Calculating
   String output = Calculating.calculating(stringForProcessing);
   ```

   this one is pretty redundant. The code is self-explanatory. Or at least should be (again, split it into multiple methods).

   So don't explain what. Explain *why*.

   ```
   //checking value for negativity
   if ((workingString.charAt(position) == '-')
           && (position == 0
                   || workingString.charAt(position - 1) == '-'
                   || workingString.charAt(position - 1) == '+'
                   || workingString.charAt(position - 1) == '*'
                   || workingString.charAt(position - 1) == '/')) {
   ```

   So this one checks for negativity. Cool. That comment should have been a method name `private static boolean checkNegative(String workingString, int pos)`. Or something similar.

   The comment? Not needed.

   What I don't understand (usually until I dive really deep into the code) is why is the condition so long and why is it checking previous characters, too. That should be commented: `// checking previous chars, because of ...`
4. Cache often used values.

   If you wrote `workingString.charAt(position - 1)` four times in a condition, you probably should have used

   ```
   char previousChar = workingString.charAt(position - 1);
   ```

   And then use this cached value in your condition. Your lines will be shorter, your code will be more clear and faster.

   Same problem:

   ```
   if (Float.valueOf(result) == Math.floor(Float.valueOf(result))) {
       result = Integer.toString(Math.round(Float.valueOf(result)));
   }
   return result;
   ```

   Use:

   ```
   float numResult = Float.valueOf(result);
   if (numResult == Math.floor(numResult)) {
       result = Integer.toString(Math.round(numResult));
   }
   return result;
   ```

   This issue is all around your code and would help quite a lot when gotten right. However, don't obsess about caching too much - it can hurt readability when used excessively. And readability should be one of your main concerns.
5. If you want to use something as a stack, look for a implemetation of stack, don't use a `List`. Your code will be much more readable, because you won't have to call `stack.get(stack.size() - 1)`, but will use `stack.getLast()` instead.

   Also, try to avoid [`java.util.Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) for reasons you don't yet understand (think "it's old"). Use a [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface and a [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) (preferred) or [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implementation.

   ```
   Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
   ```
6. When done with this, instead of your old

   ```
   while (Stack.size() > 0) {
       ResultArr.add(Stack.get(Stack.size()-1));
       Stack.remove(Stack.size() - 1);
   }
   ```

   you'll end up with code like this:

   ```
   while (stack.size() > 0) {
       resultArr.add(stack.getLast());
       stack.removeLast();
   }
   ```

   While visibly better, it can still be improved to:

   ```
   while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
       resultArr.add(stack.removeLast());
   }
   ```
7. You're parsing strings to numbers, then performing operations on them and then converting them back to strings. Highly inefficient and confusing both for you and for me. Consider storing numbers as ... numbers. I admit that to do this effectively and nicely, you'll probably need to write some classes or enums. That is a step up from your current programming level, so don't bother with it until you're sure what you're doing at the current level. But it's something to consider. [The same applies to operations which can be implemented as enums/classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926155/calculator-without-if-else-or-switch)

Wow. I didn't expect this to get so long. It's definitely not all the things that could use some polishing, but it's what caught my eye while going through. I think it's enough for today :).

Answer (score 3):

[Slanec's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/29060/26200) explains it's all. But I would like to add some points.

1. If you are writing your code in any IDE, try to use some source code analyzer like [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/). It will complain about unnecessary code content.
2. Your `boolean` field `Error` doesn't change and always stays as `false`. So I think you don't need to use that field. So the code snippet

   ```
   if(Main.Error){          //return error report
       return(workingString);
   }
   ```

   will not execute ever and makes it unnecessary.
3. Try to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your code and remember to [Do Only One Thing](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop).